# How to use tokio StreamExt return types?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

Suppose I have a function filtering an asynchronous wrapper stream e.g.

```
use futures_util::Stream;
use tokio_stream::{wrappers::{BroadcastStream, errors::BroadcastStreamRecvError}, StreamExt};

pub fn filter_even(stream: BroadcastStream<i32>) -> PrivateFilterType 
{
    stream.filter(|n| if let Ok(m) = n { m % 2 == 0 } else { false })
}
```

Then the return type is some Filter, which is in a private Module of [tokio-stream](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/tokio-stream/src/stream_ext/filter.rs), so I cannot use it. I can fall back to the trait and return a implementation e.g.

```
pub fn filter_even<S: Stream<Item = i32>>(stream: S) -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream.filter(|s| s % 2 == 0)
}
```

with suitable adjustments for the Item based on the Wrapper stream. But then this propagates through my code in places where I can't use `impl` e.g.:

```
pub struct NumberThing {
   pub numbers: impl Stream
}
```

Ideally I want to have the same argument Wrapper Stream type instead of `PrivateFilterType`. Is that possible and if not what are my alternatives?
In case of a dynamic trait implementation, do I need to use `Box<dyn Stream<Item = ...>>` everywhere, where I can't use `impl Stream`?

Comment: "then this propagates through my code, as the size is not statically known" - could you share an example of code generating this error? `impl Trait` is `Sized`, since it's speciic type, not `dyn Trait`.

Comment: originally I needed it in struct properties, which is still an RFC. But i just realized that in these cases boxed types resolve the issue and I can continue using `impl` in functions. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just return an `impl Stream`:

```rust
use futures_util::Stream;
use tokio_stream::{wrappers::{BroadcastStream, errors::BroadcastStreamRecvError}, StreamExt};

pub fn filter_even(stream: BroadcastStream<i32>) -> impl Stream
{
    stream.filter(|n| if let Ok(m) = n { m % 2 == 0 } else { false })
}
```